# Removing the last index Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am playing with the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` of mysql.
I have the records:

```
DOE, JOHN TEST
JONES, TOM ERIC MIDDLENAME
```

I wanted it to output in this respective pattern:

```
DOE, JOHN T.
JONES, TOM ERIC M.
```

I am able to get last index using `SUBSTRING_INDEX((NAME), ' ', - 1` and able to output the initial by `SUBSTR( SUBSTRING_INDEX(( NAME ), ' ', - 1 ), 1, 1 )`

How can I remove the last index so that I can replace it with the initials?

Comment: It's nearly always a bad idea to place your business logic in MySQL world. Because It cripples your application's -ities like debuggability, testability.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more string manipulation should get you there

```
set @a = 'DOE, JOHN TEST';
set @b = 'JONES, TOM ERIC MIDDLENAME';


select  concat(
            trim(replace(@a, substring_index(@a,' ',-1) ,'')),
            ' ',
          left(
            substring_index(@a,' ',-1)
            ,1)
            ,'.') a,
            concat(
            trim(replace(@b, substring_index(@b,' ',-1) ,'')),
            ' ',
          left(
            substring_index(@b,' ',-1)
            ,1)
            ,'.')   b
;

+--------------+--------------------+
| a            | b                  |
+--------------+--------------------+
| DOE, JOHN T. | JONES, TOM ERIC M. |
+--------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```